# Get raw transaction from tx id without txindex=1

Tags: json-rpc, raw-transaction, bitcoin-cli, txindex

I'm trying to get the raw transaction hex string of a transaction that I know the id from.

I would like to do that without using txindex=1.

As I assume the transaction is unspent (and confirmed) I'm doing the following steps:

`bitcoin-cli gettxout 'txid'`

`bitcoin-cli getblockcount`

`bitcoin-cli getblockhash 'blockcount - txout.confirmations + 1'`

`bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 'txid' 0 'blockhash'`

I have a race condition when getting the blockcount.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a race condition with `getblockcount`, you could use `getblockheader` with the `bestblock` result from `gettxout` and get its height. Then do the height calculation with the number of confirmations to get the block hash to pass to `getrawtransaction`.